# Cannot resolve method 'withZone' in 'OffsetDateTime'

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time, datetime-conversion

I have the following code that I want to migrate to Java 17:

Gradle dependency:

```
implementation 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:7.0.0.CR1'
```

Entity:

```
    import org.joda.time.DateTime;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "logs")
    public class Log {
    
      @Column(name = "inserted_date")
      @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
      private DateTime insertedDate;
    }


.....

DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

log.setInsertedDate(DateTime.now());
dateFormatter.print(log.getInsertedDate().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)));
```

I updated the code to this:

Entity:

```
    import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "logs")
    public class Log {
    
      @Column(name = "inserted_date")
      private OffsetDateTime insertedDate;
    }


.....

DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

log.setInsertedDate(OffsetDateTime.now());
dateFormatter.print(log.getInsertedDate().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)));
```

But I get error `Cannot resolve method 'withZone' in 'OffsetDateTime'`. Do you know what is the proper way to update method `withZone`?

***edit***: I tried this

from:      `log.setTimestamp(dateFormatter.print(auditLog.getInsertedDate().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)));`

to:     `log.setTimestamp(dateFormatter.print(auditLog.getInsertedDate().atZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)));`

I get for this line: `auditLog.getInsertedDate().atZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)` error:

`Cannot resolve method 'print(ZonedDateTime)'`

Can you advice how to solve this?

Comment: Do you mean `atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId)`

Comment: sorry can you clarify more?

Comment: The method `atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId)` seems to be the closest equivalent of `org.joda.time.DateTime.withZone(..)` for `java.time.OffsetDateTime`. Or maybe you intended to use `java.time.Instant`, and then you'd need to use the method `atZone(ZoneId)`.

Comment: ok but for `atZoneSameInstant(.....)` what argument I need to pass which will be same as `DateTimeZone.UTC`?

Comment: Do you mean to migrate from the *Joda-Time* library to the *java.time* classes built into Java 8+? If so, say so. Edit the body of your Question.

Comment: I want to migrate the code to java 17 but keeping the same functionality as much as I can. Can you guide me how to do it properly, please?

Comment: You can use `ZoneOffset.UTC`, or `ZoneId.of("UTC")`

Comment: That said, migrating to Java 17 has nothing to do with switching to Jodatime. The `java.time` classes have been there since Java 8, and as far as I'm aware, Jodatime works fine on Java 17.

Comment: I updated the post with your proposal but I get now error: `Cannot resolve method 'print(ZonedDateTime)'`

Comment: @PeterPenzov Just trying to migrate by trying to replace types and ask a question or comment for each compilation error you get is not a fruitful exercise. Study the actual API and you'll see that the [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) doesn't have a `print` method (you probably want `format`).

Comment: Sorry but the code is very critical and I don't have much of experience with DateTime. I get `Cannot resolve method 'format' in 'DateTimeFormatter'` There is no method format.

Comment: Then you're probably still using the `DateTimeFormatter` of Joda-Time, not of Java. And if the code is so critical, then either don't migrate away from Joda-Time, or it should be done by someone with more experience in Joda-Time and the java.time API. As far as I'm aware, it works fine on Java 17, so that cannot be the reason why you're migrating away from it.

Comment: yes, you're right. Last question which formatter I need to use for Java time?

Comment: `.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)`?

Comment: `log` is the entity (public class Log {...})

Comment: I got confused because you are trying to call `log.setTimestamp()` but in your `Log` entity I don’t see any `setTimestamp` method? Which type has its parameter got?

Comment: You format string `yy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` is weird and wrong (both in the old and the new code). It is trying to be [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), but in ISO 8601 two digit year is not allowed. The first lower case `mm` is wrong as explained in the answer. Putting `Z` in quotes is wrong too. It’s the offset, so format the offset from the datetime. To produce proper ISO 8601 you don’t need a format pattern string since both Joda-Time and java.time produce ISO 8601 natively.

Comment: So to produce a string, assuming `auditLog` is a `Log`: `auditLog .getInsertedDate() .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC) .toString()`. Or if you don’t want the fraction of second: `... .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC) .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS) .toString()`.

Comment: (You may know this already), for better response to your question (1) provide full reproducible code ([mre]) (2) add all the right tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it looks like your time format isn't what you intended it to be.

"yy-**mm**-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" would mean a format that prints:

*year-minutes-days'T'Hours(24 hour format):minutes:secondsZ*

example: 23-**48**-19T14:48:17Z

I'm assuming you want to follow years with month of the year and so the format should be:

"yy-**MM**-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"

example: 23-**02**-19T14:48:17Z

To know more about constructing patterns for formatting please refer the section **"Patterns for Formatting and Parsing"** in the [java time api docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Now, coming to your question,

 You seem to be mixing the [joda time library](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) with [java date time api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). Written purely with the java date time api, your code should look something like:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;


DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
log.setInsertedDate(OffsetDateTime.now());
log.setTimestamp(dateFormatter.format(auditLog.getInsertedDate().atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"))));
```

PS: I know that working with date time objects can be frustrating and confusing in Java especially because there used to be more than one way to do it. I would recommend reading the [java date time api tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) to get a better understanding and to always use it (when writing in java 8+) to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One follow-up question which is not clear to me. Should I use  `joda time library` or `java date time api` from Java 17?

Comment: [The Joda-time homepage](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) answera that part clearly: *Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).*