# Migrate org.joda.time to java.time and set time zone

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to migrate this code:

```
private Resource getRegistrations(DateTime startDate) {   
    DateTime pageStartDate = (startDate == null) ? null : startDate.withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.UTC);    
    return ........;
  }
```

to this:

```
private Resource getRegistrations(OffsetDateTime startDate) {
    OffsetDateTime pageStartDate = (startDate == null) ? null : startDate.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toOffsetDateTime();
    return null;
  }
```

Is this the proper way `atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toOffsetDateTime();` To set the time zone?

Comment: Using Joda-Time `withZoneRetainFields()` is unusual. Are you sure it’s what you always wanted? Could it be that it just happens to give you the expected result because in practice the incoming `DateTime` was already in UTC?

Comment: Stop posting the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76028526/839733) repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

No.

`withZoneRetainFields` keeps the 'fields' - year, month, day, hour, minute - those are fields. By changing the timezone, the first snippet means that the timestamp returned **is not the same** as the input value. Given the name `getRegistrations` it strongly sounds to me like **the first code is wrong**. This happens: You are refactoring, and you found a bug.

The second snippet maintains the same instant. In other words, if you have, say, '5 o'clock in the afternoon, december 20th, in london' and you use `atZoneSameInstant` to get a time in the `Europe/Amsterdam` zone, you'd get **6** o clock back (because when it's 5 o'clock in london, it's 6 in amsterdam, amsterdam is in a time zone 1 hour ahead of britain).

The first snippet would give you 5 o'clock in amsterdam which is in fact 1 hour earlier.

Note that `OffsetDateTime` is the one you should almost never use. You probably want `ZonedDateTime`. The problem with offsets is that they do not map onto any reckoning at all. Computers don't like offsets (they like millis-since-an-epoch), and humans don't use offsets, they use timezones. There's no difference if it's a zone that doesn't have daylight savings, but many do.

Your variable is also wrong. Why is a `DateTime` object called `pageStartDate`?

If you are just interested in *dates*, then use `LocalDate`. If it's actually about a specific moment in time by human reckoning, use `ZonedDateTime`. If it's about computer systems / raw comparisons (you just want to know which event amongst a whole bunch of em was 'earlier' than another, you don't really care about which date it was on, for example), then use `java.time.Instant`.

`ZonedDateTime pageStart

Comment: Let me give you some additional clarification what I'm doing: The original filed that I have is using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75428799/cannot-resolve-method-withzone-in-offsetdatetime  I want to migrate `org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime` (org.joda.time.DateTime) to `java.time.OffsetDateTime` Do you think am I using `OffsetDateTime` properly or there is a better alternative?

Comment: jodatime `withZone` translates to `atZoneSameInstant`, and `withZoneRetainFields` becomes `withZoneSameLocal`. jodatime's `DateTime` mostly becomes `ZonedDateTime`, it's not quite a 1v1 translation, but that's a much, much better option than `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: ok, can you guide me how I have to edit the original code when I use `ZonedDateTime`?

Comment: There aren't anywhere near enough details in your post to do such a thing. What more do you need to know? The original snippet changes the instant in time, only you know if that is correct or not. If it is, use `withZoneSameLocal`, if it is not, use `withZoneSameInstant` and make sure the rest of the team knows you also fixed a bug as part of your refactor. Replace `OffsetDateTime` with `ZonedDateTime`. If there is an issue with doing that, post a new question explaining why ODT works when ZDT doesn't.